# Loading events on start from database

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I want to load all the events from the database in the calendar as the page loads but it's not working. Thedata is comming to the page from database but the object is not showing events.

My model is

```
 public class Calendar
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }

        public DateTime starttime { get; set; }
        public DateTime endtime { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller methods are

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult dataReceiver(string title)
{
    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.title = title;
    calendar.starttime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    calendar.endtime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().AddDays(5);
    db.Calendars.Add(calendar);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(title, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public ActionResult datasender()
{
    var search = from m in db.Calendars select m;
    //ViewBag.Message = search.ToList();
    return Json(search.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and my view is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Calendar</title>
    <link href="~/Content/calendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/calendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media='print' />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .fc-ltr {
            background: #ddba8f;
        }

        .fc-toolbar {
            background: #c64343;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id='calendar' style="height:90%; width:90%; color:black; border:1px solid blue; margin-top:5%; position:relative">

    </div>
</body>
</html>

@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/calendar/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/calendar/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/calendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/calendar/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            calendarcreate();
            var obj;
        });

        function calendarcreate() {
              $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Calendar/datasender",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert("successfull data received " + JSON.stringify(obj));
                    var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
                        selectable: true,
                        selectHelper: true,
                        select: function (start, end) {
                            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                            var eventData;
                            if (title) {
                                eventData = {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end
                                };
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                            }
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "Post",
                                url: "/Calendar/dataReceiver",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: { "title": eventData.title },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("successfull data send " + data);
                                                          },
                                error: function (req, status, error) {
                                    alert(error + req + status);
                                                                       }
                                    });
                        },
                        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                            alert(calEvent.title + calEvent.start + calEvent.end +obj)
                                                                         },
                        dragOpacity: .50,
                        dragRevertDuration: 1000,
                        eventColor: '#378006',
                        eventBackgroundColor: 'gray',
                        editable: true,
                        eventStartEditable: true,
                        eventDurationEditable: true,
                        dragScroll: true,
                        eventOverlap: false,
                        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        events:
                            [
                            {
                                title: 'All Day Event',
                                start: '2015-02-01'
                            },

                            {
                                id: 999,
                                title: 'Repeating Event',
                                start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
                            },

                            {
                                title: 'Click for Google',
                                url: 'http://google.com/',
                                start: '2015-02-28'
                            }
                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert(error + req + status);
                    var div = $('#SearchItemDiv');
                    div.html("");
                    div.append('Error');
                }
            });


            }


    </script>
```

Comment: Is this Java? Please tag your question better. It's not getting any views because it's not showing up on anyone's feeds.

Comment: it is dotnet c# and i am using this via mvc..and view is in razor view

Comment: take the full calendar setup out of the ajax call, break out each thing you are trying to do so you can isolate the issue.  Have full calendar setup on document.ready, then add event source from the database on a seperate call after full calendar is displayed with initial data.

Comment: i understand that you are saying me to seprate all the portions (Except event) outside of the ajax method .but that is not woorking.actually i want to load all the events from the memory(database) at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function calendarcreate() {
              $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Calendar/datasender",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item)
                        {
                            item.start = new Date(item.start);
                            item.end = new Date(item.end);
                      });
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);

                    alert("successfull data received " + JSON.stringify(obj));
                    var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
                        selectable: true,
                        selectHelper: true,
                        select: function (start, end) {
                            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                            var eventData;
                            if (title) {
                                eventData = {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end
                                };
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                            }
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "Post",
                                url: "/Calendar/dataReceiver",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: { "title": eventData.title },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("successfull data send " + data);
                                                          },
                                error: function (req, status, error) {
                                    alert(error + req + status);
                                                                       }
                                    });
                        },
                        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                            alert(calEvent.title + calEvent.start + calEvent.end +obj)
                                                                         },
                        dragOpacity: .50,
                        dragRevertDuration: 1000,
                        eventColor: '#378006',
                        eventBackgroundColor: 'gray',
                        editable: true,
                        eventStartEditable: true,
                        eventDurationEditable: true,
                        dragScroll: true,
                        eventOverlap: false,
                        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        events:
                            [
                            {
                                title: 'All Day Event',
                                start: '2015-02-01'
                            },

                            {
                                id: 999,
                                title: 'Repeating Event',
                                start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
                            },

                            {
                                title: 'Click for Google',
                                url: 'http://google.com/',
                                start: '2015-02-28'
                            }
                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert(error + req + status);
                    var div = $('#SearchItemDiv');
                    div.html("");
                    div.append('Error');
                }
            });


            }
```

Just added following line in questions and calendar renders:

```
            $.each(data, function (i, item)
                {
                    item.start = new Date(item.start);
                    item.end = new Date(item.end);
              });
```